# Change current folder in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file fetching some other files:

## start.js

```
require("./users");
```

but the users.js file is not in the current folder but in model/.

I want to be able to run:

```
node start.js model
```

and it would assume that ./ is the same as model/ in start.js.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to make Node.js recognize the folder `model` as a module.

In order to do that, you need to place a file called `index.js` inside the `model` folder.

```
//  model/index.js
exports.users = require('./users'); //  model/users.js
exports.posts = require('./posts'); //  model/posts.js
// etc.
```

Now you can import the `model` module and access it's exports:

```
var models = require('./model');
models.users.create(); // some function exported in model/users.js
models.posts.list(); // this was exported in model/posts.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add ./model dir to require.paths array:

```
require.paths.unshift("./model");
var
  users = require("users"), // It works!
  posts = require("posts");
```

But I want to ask you: why do you need this instead of using

```
var
  users = require("./model/users"), // It works!
  posts = require("./model/posts");
```

?

Comment: That's stupid, adding stuff to paths is not encouraged in any way, and he did not want to use the `model` prefix. Using the `index.js` approach is the normal way of doing this, NPM wraps all the installed modules this way.

Comment: I concur that adding the the paths is bad practice. But personally I would use `./model/users`  for readability

Comment: Well if he would want to distribute a whole lib with several sub modules, then the `index.js` approach is still the best, gives a better black box view too.